# Erorr with the nullpointer

Tags: java

```
    public class List {
        private class Node {
            public Node next = null;
            Object element;
            Node text;

            Node(Object element, Node prevNode) {
                this.element = element;
                prevNode = this;
            }

            Node(Object element) {
                this.element = element;
                element = null;
            }
        }

        private Node head;
        private Node tail;
        private int count;

        public List() {
            this.head = null;
            this.tail = null;
            this.count = 0;
        }

        public void add(Object item) {
            if (head == null) {
                // We have empty list
                head = new Node(item);
                tail = head;
            } else {
                // We have non-empty list
                Node newNode = new Node(item, tail);
                tail = newNode;
            }
            count++;
        }

        public Object remove(int index) {
            if (index >= count || index < 0) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid index: " + index);
            }
            // Find the element at the specified index
            int currentIndex = 0;
            Node currentNode = head;
            Node prevNode = null;
            while (currentIndex < index) {
                prevNode = currentNode;
                currentNode = currentNode.next;
                currentIndex++;
                count--;
                if (count == 0) {
                    head = null;
                    tail = null;
                } else if (prevNode == null) {
                    head = currentNode.next;
                } else {
                    prevNode.next = currentNode.next;
                }

            }
            return currentNode.element;

        }

        public int remove(Object item) {
            // Find the element containing searched item
            int currentIndex = 0;
            Node currentNode = head;
            Node prevNode = null;
            while (currentNode != null) {
                if ((currentNode.element != null && currentNode.element
                        .equals(item))
                        || (currentNode.element == null)
                        && (item == null)) {
                    break;
                }
                prevNode = currentNode;
                currentNode = currentNode.next;
                currentIndex++;
            }
            if (currentNode != null) {
                // Element is found in the list. Remove it
                count--;
                if (count == 0) {
                    head = null;
                    tail = null;
                } else if (prevNode == null) {
                    head = currentNode.next;
                } else {
                    prevNode.next = currentNode.next;
                }
                return currentIndex;
            } else {
                // Element is not found in the list
                return -1;
            }
        }

        public int indexOf(Object item) {
            int index = 0;
            Node current = head;
            while (current != null) {
                if ((current.element != null && current.element.equals(item))
                        || (current.element == null) && (item == null)) {
                    return index;
                }
                current = current.next;
                index++;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        public boolean contains(Object item) {
            int index = indexOf(item);
            boolean found = (index != -1);
            return found;
        }

        public Object elementAt(int index) {
            if (index >= count || index < 0) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid index: " + index);
            }
            Node currentNode = this.head;
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                currentNode = currentNode.next;
            }
            return currentNode.element;
        }

        public int getLength() {
            return count;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws NullPointerException {
            List shoppingList = new List();
            shoppingList.add("Milk");
            shoppingList.add("Honey");
            shoppingList.add("Olives");
            shoppingList.add("Beer");
            shoppingList.remove("Olives");
            System.out.println("We need to buy:");
            for (int i = 0; i < shoppingList.getLength(); i++) {
                System.out.println(shoppingList.elementAt(i));
            }
            System.out.println("Do we have to buy Bread? "
                    + shoppingList.contains("Bread"));
        }
    }
```

Its giving me that in maina and index of have nullpointer. 
Where is my mistake ? 
And i want to know how to fix this problem. Thank you.
I would be very grateful if you could give me some feedback for code.

Comment: Please format your code correctly and let us know which line is throwing the NPE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not set `next` when you create your Nodes, so `next` is always null.

This

```
    Node(final Object element, Node prevNode) {
        this.element = element;
        prevNode = this;
    }
```

should be

```
    Node(final Object element, Node prevNode) {
        this.element = element;
        prevNode.next = this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand there's something in your code that's giving you nullpointerException when you run the program, but there's no need of it being in the main method, any method called by main may be giving the exception. Still, try this:

Replace this line:

```
for (int i=0; i<shoppingList.getLength(); i++) {
```

by this one:

```
for (int i=0; i < shoppingList.length(); i++) {
```

if .length() doesn't work, maybe .size() will do.

```
for (int i=0; i<shoppingList.size(); i++) {
```

If you are using eclipse, netbeans or any other environment, post which line is throwing the NullPointerException. We can't help you unless you give us more data.